# Find and replace between first '>' and next '<' in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I have an html table with some headers:

```
<th>Header01</th>
...
<th>Different Header 20</th>
```

I'd like to find and replace everything between the first `>` and the next `<` with `{{   }}`:

```
<td>{{   }}</td>
...
<td>{{   }}</td>
```

I know I can use `:s/\%Vth/td/g` to replace all the `th` with `td`, but how can I use Vim's regex to find and replace everything between `>` and `<` with `{{    }}`?

I have attempted the following without success

```
:s/\%V\>(.*?)\</{{   }}/g
```

Comment: Do not escape `<` and `>`. Lazy quantifier in Vim is `{-}`. Try `s/\v>.{-}</{{   }}/g`

Comment: As a general rule, [you shouldn't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4934172). It might work for a simple HTML but using an HTML parser is usually a better idea.

Comment: Ok, `%s/>\(.\{-}\)</>{{ \1 }}</g` should work. Remove `\1` to just get an empty braces substring.

Comment: To be clear, I am doing a find and replace while in Vim visual selection mode. Does this make a difference? I'm a little confused on the warning @AhmedAbdelhameed. I am not trying to parse HTML with regex, I am trying to find and replace in visual selection mode for lines where I know that the characters '>' and '<' exist. Is this the same thing?

Comment: It just means you understand that the regex cannot fit all kinds of mark-up language syntax and there will be edge cases when regex might find something you do not want, or vice versa.

Comment: @ScottSkiles You will just need to be a little bit careful when doing "find and replace" with regex (on HTML) because your regex might not match what you think it will (in some cases) specially if you have some complicated HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Makes sense. I'll accept an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you would take the risk of changing a html/vim by regex, in vim, you can just do:

```
%s/>[^<]*</>{{ & }}</g
```

Comment: What is the risk you're referring to @Kent?

Comment: @ScottSkiles [The one Ahmed warned you of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/590789/4934172).

Comment: @ScottSkiles for example you have `<![CDATA[.....` crossing multiple lines, or there were `<br>, <p> etc` in one `<td>..</td>` well, you know your input best, if you are sure it will work, just do it.

Comment: Ahh thank you both. I did not see the initial comment from Ahmed.

Comment: @Kent, I modified the above to run in Vim's visual mode, only selecting the lines that I want to change. Is this still dangerous?

Comment: @ScottSkiles I rejected your edit. because, if you selected lines, when you pressed `:`, the range will be there automatically. `%V` is for matching, not for ranging. again, it is risky, no matter if it will apply on selected lines or whole file, the point is, it is not good in general to change html/xml with regex

Comment: @Kent - Okay! Thanks for the edit reject explanation. Does it make a difference if this is modifying HTML tags in a Django template as opposed to an xml/html file? Still trying to grock the concept.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
%s/>\(.\{-}\)</>{{ \1 }}</g
```

In a non-very magic mode, `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries that is why they did not work on your side. Besides, `*?`, a Perl-like lazy quantifier, should be written as `\{-}` in Vim. The `%` symbol at the start tells Vim to search and replace on all lines, not just the current one.

**Details**

- `>` - matches a `>`
- `\(.\{-}\)` -  captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars (but linebreaks, if you need to include line breaks, prepend `.` with `\_`) but as few as possible
- `<` - matches a `<`

The replacement is `>{{ \1 }}<`, `>{{`, Group 1 value and `}}>`. `g` makes multiple search and replace operations on lines.

Answer (score 0):

I may be misreading the question, but it appears the desired replacement text is paired double braces around 3 whitespaces (not around the original matched text: *"replace everything between the first > and the next < with {{   }}"*. If correct, then the following simple substitute command should work:

```
%s/>.*</>{{   }}</g
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one tag -->  content  per line, you can do:

```
:%norm cit{{ }}
```

As you would know, "cit" is a vim text-object that stands for "Change Inner Tag".
If you have many tags on each line you can try:

```
:%s,>\zs[^<]*\ze</.*,{{ }},g
```

For more read `:h text-objects` and `:h \zs`